# Returning null value in dictionary of JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Write a function named "json_average" that takes a JSON formatted string as a parameter in the format of an array of objects where each object has keys "mass", "density", "temperature", and "velocity" and each key maps to a floating point number. This function should return the average "velocity" of all the objects in the array as a JSON string in the format {"velocity": }

```js
function json_average(JSON1){
    var load = JSON.parse(JSON1);
    var sum = 0;
    var sum1 = 0;
    var dictionary = {};
    for (var i in load){
        sum += i.velocity;
        sum1 += 1;
    }
    var average = sum / sum1;
    dictionary.velocity = average;
    return JSON.stringify(dictionary);
}

console.log(json_average('[{"velocity": 1}, {"velocity": 10}]'));
```

I keep returning the value of 'velocity' as null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us a sample JSON1 input?

Comment: Input: [{"density": 991.99, "mass": 47.78, "temperature": 42.88, "velocity": 33.55}, {"density": 392.54, "mass": 44.06, "temperature": -1.77, "velocity": 70.79}]    Output: {"velocity": 52.17}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's an array, you want to use [`for i of load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
function json_average(JSON1) {
  var load = JSON.parse(JSON1);
  var sum = 0;
  var sum1 = 0;
  var dictionary = {};
  for (var i of load) {
    sum += i.velocity;
    sum1 += 1;
  }
  var average = sum / sum1;
  dictionary.velocity = average;
  return JSON.stringify(dictionary);
}

console.log(json_average('[{"velocity": 1}, {"velocity": 10}]'));
```

`for...in` is used to iterate over keys of an object.

Comment: I always wonder this. What is the difference between 'for i of load' and 'for i in load'?

Comment: for..in iterates over all enumerable property keys of an object, here in your case its array indices. And for..of iterates over the values of an iterable object.